# NSDateFormatter format to parse long-form date with '(UTC)' (from MIME header)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to parse some dates from old email messages' MIME headers:

```
"Sun, 31 Aug 2008 23:38:35 +0000 (UTC)"
```

Because there are a bunch of different ones, I'm creating date formatter strings in a loop. Unfortunately none of these are capturing this one, though, and I don't know why?

```
let date = "Sun, 31 Aug 2008 23:38:35 +0000 (UTC)"

extension String {
    func toDate() -> Date? {

        var date: Date?
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let formats = [
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
            "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (z)",
            "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
        ]
        formats.forEach { (format) in
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
            if let parsed = dateFormatter.date(from: self) {
                date = parsed
            } else {
                print(":(")
            }
        }

        return date
    }
}

date.toDate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format `"E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (z)"` works for `"Sun, 31 Aug 2008 23:38:35 +0000 (UTC)"`. But it will only work if the user's locale is set to English. When parsing fixed format date strings, be sure you set the date formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

This not only ensure it properly handles the English weekday and month names, it also avoids issues if the user has changes the 12/24-hour time setting on their device.

Comment: Ah, OK thanks. What's impact of doing this for other locales (e.g. if someone from Germany has a different date format?)

Comment: I was under the impression these were fixed format strings in English. If the date strings will always be in the user's current language then you do not want to use this special locale. But a German user will not be able to parse dates with English. If you need to handle that case, maybe you need two loops. One in the user's locale and one in the special locale.

Comment: Yeah, OK that's what I thought. This is just something I encountered when looking at my own personal email, chances are there are a whole bunch of other extraneous date formats out there.